# How to download a file with Selenium when it's imposible to use WebDrivers with GUI?

Tags: c#, azure, selenium, phantomjs

I need to download a pdf file with Selenium. This pdf file is downloaded when a button is clicked. The URL of the file isn't accesible, the button submit a form and the server response directly with the file (without confirm dialog).

I'm using PhantomJS WebDriver (the project is in C#) because the application will be an Azure webapp, so I can't use ChromeDriver or similar. The problem is that PhantomJS can't deal with binary files, so when I simulate the click in the button the app doesn't download anything.

Any ideas??

P.D: Selenium is not only for the pdf download, the project do a lot of scrapping with it.

Comment: you don't have to interact with file itself just the button; so you just need to click.. am I right? you can use a custom waitAndClick() method which waits for element to be visible, clickable and then uses Actions class to focus the element and click it

Comment: Probably I haven't expressed it very well... When the button is clicked, the download is started (when I use, for example, ChromeDriver). But nothing happen when the button is "clicked" with PhantomJS.

Comment: okay, well you can try click using selenium's `JavascriptExceutor` to clcik that button element

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The problem is that whem Selenium click the button (usin PhantomJS) nothing happen, because it can't handle binary files so it doesn't download the file.

Comment: Yes but it can click the button which initiates download

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Azure and you are not able to fidn any solution, I would suggest greating a virtual machine with graphical interface so you can run an instance of ChromeDrive (or another one).

Comment: Probably I'll use a fork of PhantomJs that is being developed, called YorksitoJS.